# Get Sum of difference of 2 colums sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The question seems a bit confusing, I will give an example :

Table : id | begintimestamp | endtimestamp

```
     1 |      10000     |   11000
     2 |      20000     |   41000
```

Now what I want to do id that find difference of all rows of (entimestamp - begintimestamp) and then find the sum of all rows.

As shown in above table :

difference of id 1 - 1000
and difference of id 2 - 21000

and sum of all rows is 22000.

I tried this query :

```
sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select sum(total) in (SELECT " +
                        "("+WorkoutDao.Properties.EndTimeStamp.columnName +"-"+
                        WorkoutDao.Properties.BeginTimeStamp.columnName+") as total FROM "
                        + WorkoutDao.TABLENAME + " where " +
                        WorkoutDao.Properties.CauseId.columnName + " = " + causeData.getId()+")";
```

But I am no getting desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks to be phrased wrongly.  I would start with this:

```
SELECT SUM(endtimestamp - begintimestamp)
FROM yourTable;
```

It is not good to concatenate a string query together, but in this case, since it takes no parameters from the outside, it should be safe.  I can suggest this Java code based on what you included in your question:

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(" + WorkoutDao.Properties.EndTimeStamp.columnName;
sql += " - " + WorkoutDao.Properties.BeginTimeStamp.columnName + ") ";
sql += "FROM " + WorkoutDao.TABLENAME;
sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql);
```